# Searching for a sport route in the Briançon area, France

Tags: rock-climbing, sport-climbing, france

I am searching for a limestone multi-pitch sport route in France, in the Briançon area, that is nicely bolted, up to 5c (French grade) difficult and that has at least 7 pitches.

I am searching online since a while, but in vain, and maybe some local can help me quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 
[this route](http://www.camptocamp.org/routes/56132/fr/eperon-du-chemin-du-roy-che-guevaroux) that fitted perfectly.

The above link leads to the best topo I could find online (it's in French, unfortunately).

Here's a picture from that page:
[image]

It is a one-hour drive from the Ailefroide camping, according to [google maps](https://www.google.it/maps/dir/Le+Mon%C3%AAtier-les-Bains,+France/D204T,+05340+Pelvoux,+France/@44.8945734,6.385022,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x4789f743a4794da3:0xc6c4e2e2fe9efe9a!2m2!1d6.507839!2d44.976254!1m5!1m1!1s0x478a027274d9004b:0xfbbe0535ac6ef63c!2m2!1d6.4187508!2d44.9166683?hl=en). 
The Alps are really outstanding for the variety of rock you can find in such a short range.

Answer (score 3):

I was climbing around Ailefroide in the Barre des Écrins quite some time ago and my climbing level at the time was in the 5th French grade. Unfortunately I do not have a guidebook of the area and do not remember specific routes, but they were all medium long multi-pitch routes that are excellently bolted. So I guess they are well suited to your stated requirements. A guidebook to the area is [Escalades autour d´Ailefroide](http://www.kletterfuehrer.net/climbing-guides/France/Escalades-autour-dZAilefroide::1189.html).

Comment: The problem is, Ailefroide itself is granite. I was asking for limestone, which I indeed found. Time to give a self-answer to this. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: @Dakatine Ups, I overlooked that part. However the answer still served a purpose then :)